# "I can't do that, especially not in the house" vs "I can't do that, especially in the house."

Tags: difference, negation

> I can't do that, especially **not** in the house.
>
> I can't do that, especially in the house.

Are both of these sentences grammatical/acceptable? What is the difference in meaning between them?

Answer (score 1):

They actually have the same meaning.  In your first sentence

> I can't do that, especially **not** in the house.

***Especially*** is used to emphasize the prohibition.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't do that, especially **not in** the house.

means when **not in** the house, it's even harder for me to do that.

---

> I can't do that, especially **in** the house.

means when **in** the house, it's even harder for me to do that.

Comment: I feel like the first one means that it is especially true that they can’t do it while in the house. Maybe it’s ambiguous.